# Tinkerpop frame: how to create new Vertex

Tags: orientdb, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint, tinkerpop-frames

I can't persist a new vertex with Tinkerpop Frame and Blueprint (ver. 2.6).
What am I doing wrong? This is my code.. a little cleaned from parts that are not useful.
I am using OrientDb as undelying Graph database engine.

I receive no exception, but when I look in the database it is empty.
Can you notice why?
Thank you!

Frame entity:

```
public interface User extends VertexFrame{

@Property("id")
public String getId();
@Property("id")
public void getId(String Id);

@Property("email")
public String getEmail();
@Property("email")
public void setEmail(String email);

@Property("password")
public String getPassword();
@Property("password")
public void getPassword(String providerId);

@Property("firstName")
public String getFirstName();
@Property("firstName")
public void setFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

User Manager class:

```
public class UserManager implements Serializable {
    FramedGraphFactory framedFactory = new FramedGraphFactory();
    OrientGraphFactory graphFactory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:192.168.50.10:2424/database", "user", "pass");
    OrientGraph instance = graphFactory.getTx();
    FramedGraph<OrientGraph> framedGraph = framedFactory.create(instance);


    User user = framedGraph.addVertex(UUID.randomUUID(), User.class);
    user.setFirstName(profile.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(profile.getLastName());


    OrientVertex u = (OrientVertex) user.asVertex();
    u.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to commit the transaction.

Can you try using FramedTransactionalGraph?

```
FramedTransactionalGraph<OrientGraph> framedGraph = framedFactory.create(instance);

....Code....

framedGraph.commit();
```

Comment: Also if this is a green fields project then take a look at [Totorom](https://github.com/BrynCooke/totorom). It is the spiritual successor to Frames.
(Disclaimer I am the developer of Totorom)

Comment: Correct. Thank you! :)
Now the problem is updating Vertexes converted to Entities with Frames but detached from the db.. do you have any suggestion for the best practice?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187415/what-is-the-best-practice-to-update-a-vertex-after-is-detached-from-db-with-tink