# What is the best practice to update a Vertex after is detached from DB with Tinkerpop Frames?

Tags: graph, orientdb, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint, tinkerpop-frames

Let's exemplify

1. I receive a Vertex with Tinkerpop Blueprint, then I use Frames to convert it in an entity.
2. I close the database (so from now the node is detached from the DB)
3. and I show the node on a web page to let the user modify it.

The user makes some modifications, then  I shoud persist the changes.

The problem is that the Instance of the database is already closed, so the entity is detached from the database: What is the best practice (considering performance and memory usage too) to update the node?

This may be the code example:

```
 FramedGraph<OrientGraph> graph = factory.getFramedGraph();
 User user = graph.addVertex(null, User.class);
 graph.shutdown();
```

then I want to update later the node:

```
 user.name = "Donald Duck";
 user.... ?
```

Thank you,
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I found this way, that seems quite efficient:

```
public User persistUser(User user){

    FramedGraph<OrientGraph> graph = factory.getFramedGraph();

    user = graph.frame(user.asVertex(), User.class);
    factory.persist();
    graph.shutdown();
```

So the framework automatically merge back the entity to the database.
Then you have to persist.